# Can't Add iFrame App to Page

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-apps

Hey guys I'm having a hard time figuring out how to add my facebook iFrame app to my Facebook page as a page tab. I have followed the instructions to create it, and it works, but adding it has me stumped. Any thoughts? It doesn't show up on a public search...

https://apps.facebook.com/omcafacebookiframe/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try with [iframe apps](https://www.facebook.com/iframe.apps?fref=ts). Wildfire is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

1. create your page
2. access the following link, and select particular page on which the application hsa to be added.

   https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APP_ID&display=popup&next=http://www.facebook.com

Note: APP_ID is your application id.